# MongoDB -Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' in your configuration

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

My Student entity class

```
package com.example.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "student")
public class StudentMongo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8764013757545132519L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

My Repository

```
package com.example.repository;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.entity.StudentMongo;

@Repository
public class StudentMongoRepository extends SimpleMongoRepository<StudentMongo, Long> {

    @Resource
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;


    public StudentMongoRepository(MongoEntityInformation<StudentMongo, Long> metadata, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
    }

}
```

My configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = {com.example.repository.StudentMongoRepository.class})
public class MongoConfiguration {

}
```

Spring boot application

When i try to start the application i am getting following application

```
2017-11-20 09:04:48.937 ERROR 23220 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.repository.StudentMongoRepository required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' in your configuration.
```

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' in your configuration
How to create EntityInformation bean as said by spring framework
Getting above issue while running my application . how to pass entity information

suggest me how to use SimpleMongorepository

Comment: add @Service annotation to your mongoOperations class.

Comment: @Habil Why **@Service** on mongoOperations??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved externalizating the `MongoEntityInformationSupport` of Spring Data.

Do this:

Create theese three classes:

```
public final class MongoEntityInformationSupport {

    private MongoEntityInformationSupport() {}

    /**
     * Factory method for creating {@link MongoEntityInformation}.
     *
     * @param entity must not be {@literal null}.
     * @param idType can be {@literal null}.
     * @return never {@literal null}.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T, ID> MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformationFor(MongoPersistentEntity<?> entity,
                                                                      @Nullable Class<?> idType) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null!");

        MappingMongoEntityInformation<T, ID> entityInformation = new MappingMongoEntityInformation<T, ID>(
                (MongoPersistentEntity<T>) entity, (Class<ID>) idType);

        return ClassUtils.isAssignable(Persistable.class, entity.getType())
                ? new PersistableMongoEntityInformation<T, ID>(entityInformation) : entityInformation;
    }
}
```

---

Ps.: Put `PersistableMongoEntityInformation` in the same package of `MongoEntityInformationSupport`

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor //<-- Lombok
class PersistableMongoEntityInformation<T, ID> implements MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> {

    private final @NonNull
    MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> delegate;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoEntityInformation#getCollectionName()
     */
    @Override
    public String getCollectionName() {
        return delegate.getCollectionName();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoEntityInformation#getIdAttribute()
     */
    @Override
    public String getIdAttribute() {
        return delegate.getIdAttribute();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.core.EntityInformation#isNew(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean isNew(T t) {

        if (t instanceof Persistable) {
            return ((Persistable<ID>) t).isNew();
        }

        return delegate.isNew(t);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.core.EntityInformation#getId(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ID getId(T t) {

        if (t instanceof Persistable) {
            return ((Persistable<ID>) t).getId();
        }

        return delegate.getId(t);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.PersistentEntityInformation#getIdType()
     */
    @Override
    public Class<ID> getIdType() {
        return delegate.getIdType();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.EntityMetadata#getJavaType()
     */
    @Override
    public Class<T> getJavaType() {
        return delegate.getJavaType();
    }
}
```

---

I created this MongoHelper just for simplify

```
public class MongoHelper {
    public static MongoEntityInformation getEntityInformationFor(Class clazz, Class idClazz) {
        TypeInformation typeInformation = ClassTypeInformation.from(clazz);
        MongoPersistentEntity mongoPersistentEntity = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity(typeInformation);
        return MongoEntityInformationSupport.entityInformationFor(mongoPersistentEntity, idClazz);
    }
}
```

---

**Finally**

You can use like this(Sample with `QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor`):

```
public class TicketRepositoryCustomImpl extends QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor<Ticket> implements TicketRepositoryCustom {

    //The MongoOperations will be autowired
    public TicketRepositoryCustomImpl(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(MongoHelper.getEntityInformationFor(Ticket.class, String.class), mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Ticket> findWithFilter(TicketFilter filter) {
        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
        //populate the builder
        return findOne(builder.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: How is private final @NonNull
    MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> delegate; initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to say that please **DON'T USE IMPLEMENTATION CLASS INSTEAD USE AN INTERFACE**.

declare an Interface and extend it from `MongoRepository<T,ID>`, spring will provide the implementation out-of-the-box.

```
@Repository
public interface StudentMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<T,ID>{

@Autowired
private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
```

This should work.

Comment: You cannot declare a private variable in interface. By default all the variables defined in an interface are 'public static final'.
You will need to initialize all the variables defined in an interface as all variables are 'final'

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-
don't make it autowired just make a variable like this .
private  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
XXService extends PagingAndSortingRepository<XX, String>{
    
}
----------------------------------------------------------------

@Service
public class XXXmpl extends SimpleMongoRepository<XX, String> implements XXService {

    public XXImpl(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(new MongoRepositoryFactory(mongoOperations).getEntityInformation(XXX.class), mongoOperations);
    }
}
```