# Springboot adding a "_class" field in POST Request

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and I am trying to connect my SpringBoot App to MongoDB. The GET Request is working completely fine but the POST Request is adding a "_class" field in the data which I don't want. I did some searching and found that I have to add a @Configuration class to solve this issue but when I added the @Configuration class, I am getting the following error :

```
Field mongoDbFactory in com.example.demo.configuration.MongoConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory' that could not be found.
```

My Confuguration class code is as follows :-

MongoConfig.java :-

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    @Autowired
    private MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext;

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() {

        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory);
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, 
mongoMappingContext);
        converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));

        return converter;
    }
}
```

Controller.java :-

```
import com.example.demo.model.Todo;
import com.example.demo.services.TodoService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private TodoService todoService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<Todo> getTodos() {
        return todoService.getTodos();
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Todo addTodo(@RequestBody Todo todo) {
        return  todoService.addTodo(todo);
    }

}
```

TodoService.java :-

```
import com.example.demo.model.Todo;

import java.util.List;

public interface TodoService {

    public List<Todo> getTodos();

    public Todo addTodo(Todo todo);

}
```

TodoServiceImplementation.java :-

```
import com.example.demo.model.Todo;
import com.example.demo.repository.TodoRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TodoServiceImplementation implements TodoService{

 @Autowired
 private TodoRepository todoRepository;

 @Override
 public List<Todo> getTodos() {
     return todoRepository.findAll();
 }

 @Override
 public Todo addTodo(Todo todo) {
     return todoRepository.save(todo);
 }

 }
```

It is asking me to do the following action :-

```
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory' in your configuration.
```

Comment: What GET and POST requests? You haven't shown us anything Web-related at all, either code or sample data. Be careful about adding any `@Configuration` classes that seem to recite "standard" configuration (e.g., `DefaultTypeMapper`); these tutorials are often obsolete and do not reflect the fact that Boot automatically sets up most of this.

Comment: Added the Controller class above. You can check now.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: Your `todoRepository.save(todo)` creates a todo, as per the mapped POJO _and_ adds the `_class` field to the document, by default. It has a purpose - in the serialization/de-serialization from and to database data and the Java data. If you don't want the post request return the value you can exclude fields from the returned value. But, all this is an option. Ofcourse, you can try to configure to not write this field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB -Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation' in your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384779/mongodb-consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-data-mongodb-repo)